# Which of the following dependency includes LiveData Android Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-livedata

I am using LiveData and ViewModel in my new Kotlin App. But I have not added any external dependency in the gradle file. Still, my app is working fine. How is it possible? I have the following default dependency

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
```

I am confused.

Comment: Run `./gradlew app:androidDependencies` to see how all the dependencies in your app got added. You don't need to declare it to use it, as long it as gets added somehow.